# onpage load call commandbutton in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I'm trying to set value to hidden variable on page load and call  to send that value to managedbean.Onpage load i'm able to set value and call commandbutton and get value in managed bean but its going to unconditional loop and executing more than once. Here's my code.

```
<script>
window.onload = setId ;

function setId(){
var facId = document.getElementById('formname:bId').value;
document.getElementById('formname:nameId').value = facId;
document.getElementById('formname:buttonId').click();
}
</script>

<h:inputText id="nameId" value="#{bean.nameId}"></h:inputText>
<h:commandButton id="buttonId" value="fId" action="#{bean.init()}" />
```

On page load its calling the button contineously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:commandButton` submits the form and causes whole page reload due to which your script is executed again and this repeats. To avoid this one add

```
  <h:commandButton id="buttonId" value="fId" >  
      <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.init()}" />  
  </h:commandButton>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank u very much..you gave me what i need exactly. I just added execute="@form" to <f:ajax> tag then it worked.Thank you